# Telerik Rad Grid on ASP.NET MVC Razor view engine - DetailView not initially populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, grid, telerik

OK...I've spent too much time floundering on this one, so I'm passing it on to the experts -> YOU.

My VERY simple ASP.NET MVC (v3 with Razor View Engine) page uses a Telerik Rad Grid control to show some type lists and then I have the associated codes showing in the DetailsView of the grid.

Doing the population is easy.  I have a ViewModel for my TypeCodeList type and send it to the strongly typed view to populate the grid.  This works GREAT...and the grid looks great - thanks Telerik.  However, I added the DetailsView to then populate the child TypeCodes in the same manner.  The bad thing is that when my grid populates, I select the triangle on the left to expand the tree and see the child records, nothing is there.  BUT, if I select the "Refresh" button on the bottom of the grid, THEN I can hit the triangle and the child records display.

So (in summary), the child records do not show up on the initial load.  Only when I select an AJAX refresh of the grid I get the children.  Otherwise, it works as required.

I have been trying to see if I can programmatically kick off the refresh via javascrip upon page load.  OR if I can get the thing to populate by itself when selected without doing a refresh first - that would be preferable.

Below is my code:

Pertinent Controller Code (I've taken out the update, delete, insert, logging and data access methods)

```
[HandleErrorWithElmah]
public partial class HostController : Controller
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Index - Home for HostController
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    #region Type List Section

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of TypeLists - yea...say that again
    /// </summary>
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult TypeCodeList()
    {

        var model = GetActiveTypeLists();

        // Get all of the type lists and send them to the view
        return View(model);

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The ajaxified Select
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _TypeCodeList()
    {

        var model = GetActiveTypeLists();
        return Json(new GridModel(model));


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simply a wrapper to get all of the current type list values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerable<TypeCodeListViewModel> GetActiveTypeLists()
    {

        var model = from p in entityRepository.Find<TypeList>(p => p.IsActive == true)
                    select new TypeCodeListViewModel
                    {
                        TypeListId = p.TypeListId,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        IsActive = p.IsActive
                    };


        return model;

    }

    #endregion

    #region Type Code Section

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _TypeCodeForTypeListAjax(int typeListId)
    {
        var model = GetActiveTypeCodes(typeListId);
        return Json(new GridModel(model));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Simply a wrapper to get all of the current type Code values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerable<TypeCodeViewModel> GetAllActiveTypeCodes()
    {

        var model = from p in entityRepository.Find<OurLeaguePlay.Models.TypeCode>(p => p.IsActive == true).OrderBy(ord => ord.CodeName)
                    select new TypeCodeViewModel
                    {
                        TypeCodeId = p.TypeCodeId,
                        TypeListId = p.TypeListId,
                        CodeName = p.CodeName,
                        CodeValue = p.CodeValue,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        IsActive = p.IsActive
                    };


        return model;

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Simply a wrapper to get all of the current type Code values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerable<TypeCodeViewModel> GetActiveTypeCodes(int typeListId)
    {

        var model = from p in entityRepository.Find<OurLeaguePlay.Models.TypeCode>(p => p.IsActive == true && 
                                                                                        p.TypeListId == typeListId).OrderBy(ord => ord.CodeName)
                    select new TypeCodeViewModel
                    {
                        TypeCodeId = p.TypeCodeId,
                        TypeListId = p.TypeListId,
                        CodeName = p.CodeName,
                        CodeValue = p.CodeValue,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        IsActive = p.IsActive
                    };


        return model;

    }


    #endregion

}
```

Here is my View Code:
(I've taken out all of my failed javascript attempts to try and force the load on page load.)

```
    @model IEnumerable<TypeCodeListViewModel>
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc
@using OurLeaguePlay.ViewModels
@{Html.Telerik().Grid<TypeCodeListViewModel>(Model)
        .Name("TypeLists")
        .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
            Html.Telerik().Grid<TypeCodeViewModel>()
                .Name("TypeCode_<#= TypeListId #>")
                .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.TypeCodeId))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.CodeName).Width(40);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.CodeValue).ReadOnly(true).Width(40);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Description).Width(100);
                })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                    {
                        dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_TypeCodeForTypeListAjax", "Host", new { typeListId = "<#= TypeListId #>" })
                                          .Enabled(true);
                    }
                    )
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .NoRecordsTemplate("No Type Codes exist for the selected Type List")
                .ToHtmlString()
            )
        )
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.TypeListId))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Description).Width(150);
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
            }
                           ).Width(30);
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
        {
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_TypeCodeList", "Host")
                              .Update("UpdateTypeList", "Host")
                              .Insert("InsertTypeList", "Host")
                              .Delete("DeleteTypeList", "Host")
                              .Enabled(true);
            dataBinding.Server().Select("TypeCodeList", "Host", new { ajax = ViewData["ajax"] });
        }
        )
        .Editable(editable => editable.Enabled(true).Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable(page => page.PageSize(10))
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Enabled(false))
        .NoRecordsTemplate("No Type Lists can be retrieved from the database")
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
        .Render();
}
```

Finally...here are the ViewModel classes:

```
public class TypeCodeListViewModel 
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int TypeListId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 25")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage="Max Length is 25")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }


}

public class TypeCodeViewModel
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int TypeCodeId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int TypeListId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 25")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string CodeName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 25")]
    [DisplayName("Value")]
    public string CodeValue { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 500")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: If you want to get in touch with the telerik experts (I suppose you will need them) and get an advice, post your codes in their forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I think I figured it out on my own...it was as simple as just letting the grid bind itself and not forcing data into it via the non-ajax method that gets called upon initial display of the page.

The

```
Public ActionResult TypeCodeList()
```

function should simply be updated to the following:

```
Public ActionResult TypeCodeList()
{
    return View();
}
```

with no [GridAction] decorator.

If you don't force values into the grid, it will bind itself using the Ajax method and then the child grids will populate upon expansion.